# Moving everything from one table to another in sql server while converting one of the rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to move everything from one table to another table. I know how to do that if all of the columns had the same data type, however one column is different. On the new table its varcahar(24) and on the old table its a bigint. 
This is what i have so far, Im using the first select statement to set the id, and the rest to add it to the new table. However this always returns the last id, and i need it to be synced up with the second select statement

Any suggestions on how to do this would be awesome. i tried to google it for about an hour but couldnt come up with anything. I am using SQL Server 2012

```
use DatabaseA
GO

DECLARE @id bigint;


SELECT @id= columnName FROM differentDB.tableB

INSERT INTO tableA
          (buyer_id, restOfTheColumns)

Select CAST(@id AS varchar(24)), restOfTheColumns
FROM differentDB.tableB

GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables don't work like that.  T-SQL variables hold data values, not object names.  Furthermore, that's a *scalar* variable.  It only holds one value.

That said, you don't need the variable at all.  You can just do this:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (buyer_id, restOfTheColumns)
SELECT CAST(columnName AS varchar(24)), restOfTheColumns
FROM differentDB.tableB
```